# single positive dialog issue

Tags: android, dialog, onclick

just trying to get this dialog to pup up as a result of something in the overflow menu, but when i run it it crashes my code. I learned how to do so straight feom the developer site so im not sure what the issue is. here is my code:

```
public Dialog alertDialog(){

    AlertDialog.Builder aboutDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    aboutDialog.setMessage(R.string.pointlessApplication)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
             //do things
        }
    });
    return aboutDialog.create();
}
```

and like i said i want this just to be a simple "ok" dialog that pops up as the result of an "onClick"

here is the menu main.xml:

```
<item
android:id="@+id/a_More"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
android:showAsAction="always"
android:title="@string/more">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_about"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/about"
            android:onClick="alertDialog"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/settings"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED:** Needed `MenuItem item` as an argument inside of alertDialog() since the action was coming from a menu. **DOH!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 public Dialog alertDialog(){

        AlertDialog.Builder aboutDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        aboutDialog.setMessage(R.string.pointlessApplication)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 //do things
            }
        });
        return aboutDialog.create();
    }
```

Comment: eh same thing happens as what I had originally. could it be something in the menu.xml where I am calling the onClick? i mean it compiles and launches and the app briefely shows up then breaks so its not like the xml itself is broken

Comment: @erp post that code also, and also post logcat (Mention the line number where you code crashes)

Comment: posted the code, the logCat didnt say anything really but something like line 22 which is the return true inside onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: @erp edit your code snippet so any other can take a look when facing trouble